# Set image in HTML from API request node.js

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, mongodb, api

I have an API request that returns the image of the product that had been saved in the database in the form of buffer in MONGODB. The API returns the image and I want this image as source to my html element. How do I do that?

The API request is:

```
router.get('/product/avatar/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)

        if(!product || !product.avatar){
            throw new Error()
        }
        // console.log('product avatar')

        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png')
        res.send(product.avatar)
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(404).send()
    }
})
```

And this is how I was trying to assign that image to my HTML
the code snippet given below is a part of the javascript used to render information on webpage from database.

```
        var picId = data[i].name + 'Image'
        // console.log(data[i]._id)
        fetch('/product/avatar/'+data[i]._id, {
            method: 'GET'
        }).then((res) => {
            return res.json()
        }).then((data) => {
            // picId.value = data 
            // document.getElementById(picId).src = data
            console.log(data)  
        })
```

Comment: if you are returning the image from express then why would you use fetch to get the image.  you can simply put the url in src attribute and the image will be automatically picked.

Comment: and 2nd is the image stored in base64 in database ? or any other format.. you will have to decode it first and then write it to response.

Comment: Yes it helped me fix it. Thanks.